# How can someone steal from a Wild Shaped druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape

As stated in the Wild Shape druid feature (emphasis mine):

> You choose whether your equipment falls to the ground in your space, **merges into your new form**, or is worn by it.

As far as I know, this means that any equipment that the druid chooses to merge into their new form is inaccessible until they are out of their Wild Shape.

Is there any way to steal a merged item from a Wild Shaped druid without causing them to revert to their natural form?

Comment: What is the end goal of this? Is this player v player or monster v player?

Comment: Can you steal someones finger? Hair? If you cut their hair off would it revert into a worn/carried item even if it wasnt that location?

Comment: Related on [Do removed parts of a Druid's Wild Shape form persist after said Druid exits Wild Shape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86653/do-removed-parts-of-a-druids-wild-shape-form-persist-after-said-druid-exits-wil)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)

**tl;dr**
Short of the spell that can toss most of *reality's constraints* <s>the game rules</s> on their head, retrieving equipment merged into a druid's [wildshape](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#ClassFeatures) requires reverting the druid out of that wildshape.

### Merged meaning

When the equipment [merges](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merge) into the wildshape, it "become combined into one".  There is no separating it from the shape as they are the same for the duration.

### Using *Wish*

Luckily, this reality does not have to be for a sufficiently enterprising or reckless character as wish doesn't need to be bound by reality:

> By simply speaking aloud, you can alter the very foundations of reality in accord with your desires.

So the reality of the equipment being merged into one with the druid in wildshape can be altered by using wish.

#### Risks

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples. State your wish to the GM as precisely as possible. The GM has great latitude in ruling what occurs in such an instance; the greater the wish, the greater the likelihood that something goes wrong.

One would expect expending a high level and rare resource to retrieve a less valuable item from the possession of another creature is unlikely to incur "something goes wrong", but [*caveat castor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor) as there is a tradition of DMs twisting reality bending wishes.

Comment: It would be caveat caster; caveat is the 'beware' portion

Comment: There's also the question of "Is the 33% chance of never casting *Wish* again worth the risk just to get this thing from the druid?"

Comment: @BaconyRevanant If the thing in question was a bag of holding full of wish scrolls it might be worth the risk.

Comment: @Jonathan but even then, what use would have all those scrolls? If you lose the ability to cast _wish_ just to get those scrolls, those would definitely not be of any use to you.

Comment: @Jonathan that would be the kind of thing that I would expect the DM to mess with the player over.  E.g. they get a bear's bladder that functions as a bag of holding, and it's filled with rolled up papers that have "you WISH this was a spell" written on them.

Comment: @MauroScarpaleggia Hmm, having scrolls of wish but not being able to use them personally could be tricky. Who would you trust to use it for you rather than just using it for whatever they want instead?